# Transformar un proyecto angular en un archivo js

Tags: angular, script

Tengo un proyecto angular con la versión 14, necesito compilarlo en un solo archivo para poder manejarlo y llamarlo en un script desde un archivo.html diferente. Utilicé `ng build --configuration production --aot --single-bundle` pero no me hizo caso, me lo compilo en la carpeta dist en varios archivos. Como puedo pasar la carpeta dist a un solo archivo js?

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask]. "No sé cómo empezar" no es motivo suficiente en este caso como para realizar una pregunta. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué problema específico has tenido? Lee [ask]. Además, explica a qué te refieres con "quiero que aparezca en forma de modal un proyecto hecho en angular". Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Es un poco complicado de entender. Un proyecto en angular renderizaria la pagina y el modal. Es todo el framework. Posiblemente está mal entendido el problema.

Comment: Utiliza un iframe

Comment: Espero que me haya explicado mejor!

Comment: fíjate https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus y si podes coméntame